# Print values of arrays inside for loop using bash

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to print the $a and $BIT values.

But I'm receiving the value of $BIT but not $a.

Please find the code as follows,

```
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo "<html><head><META HTTP-EQUIV='refresh' CONTENT="1"></head>"
VAL[0] =1;
VAL[1] =0;
VAL[2] =1;

for CNT in $(seq 32)
do
    BIT = ${VAL[$CNT]};
    a = $(($CNT-1));

echo "<p>$a,$BIT</p>";
done
```

Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume in your original you don't have spaces around the equals (`=`)? I ran your script and it ran fine, although the `for CNT...` loop starts with `CNT` value of `1`, but you probably intend `0`. It does otherwise show the defined values of both `$a` and `$BIT`.

Comment: as @lurker says, I hope you equal signs are good. I don't see any problem otherwise.  To avoid computing the $a, you could try `for CNT in $( seq 0 31)` and your problems will go away (as @lurker says, you will have the proper array entry and no need to compute $a, just use $CNT)

Comment: Thanks luker and tgo. Problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed my code like below. My issue got resloved.

```
    echo "Content-type: text/html"
    echo ""
    echo "<html><head><META HTTP-EQUIV='refresh' CONTENT="1"></head>"
    VAL[0]=1;
    VAL[1]=0;
    VAL[2]=1;

    for CNT in $(seq 0 31)
    do
        a=$CNT;

    echo "<p>$a,$BIT</p>";
    done
```

Comment: I can't see how this _resolved_ your issue. The `$BIT` variable isn't set anywhere, and `VAL[0] =1` isn't valid Bash code due to the space.